# The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 100 in docker file

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, dockerfile

My DockerFile as follows:

```
FROM python:3.6
RUN wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.2 multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y mongodb-org
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN mongod --fork --config /etc/mongod.conf
EXPOSE 9000
```

At `apt-get update` getting an error :

```
Reading package lists...
E: Failed to fetch http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/main/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/6233101b7f58c6cf71fe1cd46b962cf358fc5626ed8cb94201f5e0e939e91d73  Connection failed [IP: 151.101.36.204 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: The error return because your image cannot connect to repo. Check your network and the address.

Comment: that also not working

Comment: actually apt-get update work with ubuntu image but not with python

Comment: Nothing you change in your source code will be able to fix that networking problem; it is likely either something specific to your host machine or the Debian upstream repositories.  Reading through the Dockerfile, though, you will be better off running a separate [`mongo`](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) container: you cannot `RUN` a background process.

Comment: This could just be a problem of the slightly legacy image version that is incompatible with some dependencies, in your case python:3.6. At least I had a similar error which vanished when I increased the version in a much older legacy Dockerfile, see ["The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 100" in a simple Ubuntu12.04 Dockerfile](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1383340/the-command-bin-sh-c-apt-get-update-returned-a-non-zero-code-100-in-a-sim). `FROM python:3.6
RUN apt-get update` runs through, though (tested).

Answer (score 0):

I have had this already twice. It vanishes when I put the version a step higher. That would mean a change for you from

FROM python:3.6

to

FROM python:3.7

(to start with). See [The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 100" in a simple Ubuntu12.04 Dockerfile - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1383340/the-command-bin-sh-c-apt-get-update-returned-a-non-zero-code-100-in-a-sim).